# Drop Down List error Message not shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, message

So I have 3 cascading drop downs and a Boat Model (`brand_id`, `year_id`, `model_id`). The errors are not shown. I have add;

```
  validates :brand_id, presence: true
  validates :year_id, presence: true
  validates :model_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
```

to `#boat.rb`. I have my form;

```
<%= form_for(@boat) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :Brand %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:brand_id,  @brands,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Brand"}, {:id => 'brands_select'}) %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :Year %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:year_id, @years, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Year"}, {:id => 'years_select'}) %>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :Model %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:model_id, @models, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Model"}, {:id => 'models_select'}) %>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <%= f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
     </div>
    <% end %>
```

And I have the `shared/errors`

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

That shared error message works perfectly for user model. And my `#create` action

```
def create
   @boat = current_user.boats.build(boat_params) if logged_in?
    if @boat.save
      flash[:success] = "Boat created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      redirect_to new_boat_path(current_user) #returns here
    end
  end
```

I call the new.html and form opens. When I press without selecting anything it redirects to `new_boat_path(current_user)` without showing errors. I dont know why.

EDIT1:
Here is the log:

```
Started GET "/boats/new.2" for 88.240.3.128 at 2015-04-16 21:58:01 +0000
Processing by BoatsController#new as 
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
```

So it renders but i do not see any errors on the page

EDIT 2: `#new` method (brand, year & model are cascading drop down lists, where Boat model has their ids)

```
def new
    @boat = Boat.new
    @brands  = Brand.all
    @years = Year.all
    @models   = Model.all
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are `redirecting` to `new_boat_path`. The `new` action creates a new instance of `Boat` which will obviously not contain any errors.

What you probably want to do is:

```
if @boat.save
  flash[:success] = "Boat created!"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render 'new'
end
```

This will not perform a redirect but just renders the `new` view which contains the @boat variable including the validation errors created by calling `@boat.save`.

Comment: I have tried that but then I get an error : `NoMethodError in BoatsController#create`  `undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass`                       `# should produce the desired results.
      def options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
        options = collection.map do |element|
          [value_for_collection(element, text_method), value_for_collection(element, value_method), option_html_attributes(element)]
        end
        selected, disabled = extract_selected_and_disabled(selected)`

Comment: I added the new method

Comment: You need to set @year, @brand & @models there again... But I suggest to just set these in your view directly. 
`<%= f.collection_select(:brand_id,  Brand.all,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Brand"}, {:id => 'brands_select'}) %>`

Comment: Keep in mind... when you call `render 'new'`, it does not call the new action in your controller. It just renders the `new` view. So you need to re-set all specific variables the view needs (in this case @brands, @models, @year). Does that makes sence?

Comment: Yes thank you, I just left only `'@boat = Boat.new` in the `#new` controller and changed the `collection_select` directly. It works now.