# Nesting the resources necessary? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

I have user model and boat model. User has many boats. Boat belongs to user. What i wonder is that, even though i did not nest the resources i am able to create a boat to logged in user. So my url becomes .`.../boats.new2` (2 as user id) and it actually saves to user with an id number 2.

But as far as i know if i have nested resources it would become something like `.../user/2/boats/1.` Isn't it?.

I have not tried to `#edit` action any of the cases so not sure which one to use and their effects, is there any other advantages using any of them, or not nesting is wrong?

Comment: Rails will never force you to nest resources. Its up to you to RESTfully create an API which mirrors the resources your app deals with.

Comment: Nesting resources in routes.rb only affects their paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting routes is not necessary in Rails. You can maintain the relationship between boats and users as long as you have the active record `belongs_to` and `has_many` methods defined in the model, along with the foreign keys in the db.

In general, you should nest resources if there is an obvious relationship between the objects, such as users and posts (or boats). It just makes more sense of your users and as an API structure.

In some cases, you might want to nest the relationship under something different, like a category name. For instance, your uri pattern could look like `/sailboats/boats/1` or `powerboats/boat/2`. Bottom line is you should structure routes in a way that logical for the project's users and developers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in this case i do not know, i can not receive the error messages that is why i though it is because of not nesting routes. Boats model has model_id brand_id and year_id. and i validated them but maybe i should use something like validates_associated?

Comment: I would probably nest the routes in your case. In the boats controller, you can handle the assignment of the model_id, brand_id, etc, based on what the user sends through the params. You would use validates_associated if the associations are necessary to create the record. If they are optional, then you don't need it.

Comment: Is there a way not nesting the routes but showing the errors?. Here is the question. [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683111/drop-down-list-error-message-not-shown) Thank you in advance